# Windows Server 2016 disabling shutdown and restart in the start menu

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to find a way to disable the Shutdown and Restart option from within the power option of the start menu for everyone including admins.

Right now the only way i can see is in the GPO to disable the whole thing in templates by changing the option `Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands` but this policy apply everywhere. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> loose the option too.

I want to remove the options only for the start menu to prevent mouse misclick. So technically all remote users should only be left with `Disconnect` option and admin that need to reboot either run the command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and reboot from there.

Comment: Tip: By default, the users without administrative privileges won't be able to restart/shutdown the server even if the option is shown in the start menu.

Comment: @Swisstone i would say 9 out of 10 connection is an actual admin and it happened a couple time already that they clicked shutdown instead of disconnect. I'm trying to avoid simple mistakes over bad UI choices. Putting a Self-Destruct button beside a light switch is never a good idea. I can't blame the users.

Comment: I've never found a way to disable those items form the Start menu without them also disappearing from the Ctrl+Alt+Delete options. I would just use the GPO, accepting that it also removes the option from the Ctrl+Alt+Delete dialog. And then have the admins use `shutdown /s` or `shutdown /r` from a command prompt to shut down or restart

Comment: @DougDeden Hold on, So this is supposed to still allow the shutdown command but all GUI option should be off ? Then that is perfect. Everyone know the command and you cannot type a command by mistake. As long as there is still 1 way other than locally login in the server i am fine with that.

Comment: Yes. The last time I tried it, it removed the options from the Start Menu and from the C-A-D screen, but still allowed the `shutdown` command to work. Give it a try.

Comment: @DougDeden We just rebooted the servers for updates and it does still work with the command line as you pointed out. Was waiting for windows update to try it to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it for Admins/Non-admins using GPO policies. Here is a reference link:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-users-shutting-down-restarting-windows-computer

Comment: Always better to provide a summary of the advice provided in your link.